# npzeros + itertuples alternative

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this :

```
user_id anime_id    user_rating
0   1   20  7.808497
1   3   20  8.000000
2   5   20  6.000000
3   6   20  7.808497
4   10  20  7.808497
```

it looks like basic dataframe for playing with recommender system.

i had ~ 7millions rows, I reduced a bit the dataframe like that :

```
df = df[df["user_id"] < 2000]
```

let's print n_users, n_items, i had 1999 users of course, and ~6000items

I have 2 problems. 
if i want to built my training dataset like that :

```
ratings = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))
for row in df.itertuples():
    ratings[row[1]-1, row[2]-1] = row[3]
```

with `ratings = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))` i got an enormous matrix that result to **memory error**.

i come with 2nd problem if i filter a few sample, this line don't return memory error but i have an **IndexError**

like that : `IndexError: index 950 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 949`

Comment: Store as sparse matrices?

Comment: i got memory error at the first line, i should pass ratings df to csr matrix ??

Comment: Add sample case https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: `np.zeros((2000, 6000)).nbytes / 1000000` gives me ~96 (MB). Is this too big for your environment to cause memory error?

Comment: No but when I take the whole dataset I have something like (70000, 6000) I found a solution my issue now is index out bound.